# expected primary-expression before token

Tags: c++

I'm kinda new to C++

I'm trying to create a "CreditCard" class inheriting an "Account parent class which doesn't have a default constructor. I'm trying to apply the initialization list as follows:

**Parent**

```
Account::Account(char *d)
{
    description = new char[strlen(d)+1];
    strcpy (description,d);
    balance=0;
}
```

**Child**

```
CreditCard::CreditCard(char *d) : Account(char *d)
{ 
    description = new char[strlen(d)+1];
    strcpy (description,d);
    balance=0;
    LIMIT=0;
}
```

but I keep getting the error **expected primary-expression before 'char'** and I cannot understand why

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: That code duplication looks like a memory leak. You don't need to repeat the base class construction in the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
 CreditCard::CreditCard(char *d) : Account(char *d)
```

to

```
 CreditCard::CreditCard(char *d) : Account(d)
```

or

```
 CreditCard::CreditCard(char *d) : Account{d}
```